# How can I do basic validation of JSON in an Excel cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, json

I have an Excel sheet that has a column that consists entirely of JSON values.

For example, cell A1:

```
{
  "selected_pet": "dog",
  "other_pets": [
    "cat",
    "mouse",
    "hamster"
  ]
}
```

From time to time, I export this sheet to CSV and then import it into a CMS (Content Management System, in this case Drupal).

This works, but I'd like to validate that the cells are actually valid JSON.  Does Excel provide any JSON validation tools?

I know Excel can input JSON into a sheet, and all my searches return results related to that.  But what I want to do is to validate the JSON inside a cell.  Does Excel have a way to do that?

I'm using Excel via Microsoft 365.

Comment: a quick search resulted in this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/json, would this work?

Comment: @gns100 The link is about importing JSON into a sheet, whereas I am trying to validate the JSON inside a cell (I don't want to generate a sheet in Excel from JSON; I want to store JSON as-is inside an Excel cell.)

Comment: I would have thought you could use PowerQuery to validate the JSON in the sheet, but I guess not.